# Displaying count instead of item name in a list (Python)

Tags: python, data-structures, queue

I am trying to make the following program display the number of fruits available at the output instead of displaying the name of the fruits but I'm unable to find out the cause of it. How do I correct it?

Basically the program will generate a random number from 1 to 5 and if number generated is below 3 (1 or 2), it is unavailable, if 3 and above, it is available.

```
import random

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = []

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.container)

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self) == 0

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.container.append(item)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.container.pop(0)

    def peek(self) :
        return self.container[0]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.container)

fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Watermelon"]
q = Queue()

temp = fruits.copy()

fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Watermelon"]
d = {fruit: random.randint(1, 5) for fruit in fruits}
unavailable = [fruit for fruit in d if d[fruit] < 3]
available = [fruit for fruit in d if d[fruit] >= 3]


for fruit in fruits:
    if random.randint(1, 5) < 3:
        unavailable.append(fruit)
    else:
        available.append(fruit)

percent_available = len(available) / (len(available) + len(unavailable)) * 100

for fruit in temp:
    q.enqueue(fruit)

    print(fruit)

    numgen = random.randint(1, 5)
    if(numgen >= 3):
        print("Item is available")
    else:
        print("Item is unavailable")

print("The following items are unavailable")
print(unavailable)
print('Number of fruits available = ' + str(available))
print('Percentage of fruits available = ' + str(percent_available))
```

**Output**

```
Apple
Item is unavailable
Orange
Item is available
Pear
Item is unavailable
Watermelon
Item is available
The following items are unavailable
['Apple', 'Watermelon', 'Apple', 'Watermelon']
Number of fruits available = ['Orange', 'Pear', 'Orange', 'Pear']
Percentage of fruits available = 50.0
```

Comment: use ``len(my_list)``?

Comment: Which part do I use that in?

Comment: Post expected output too.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
print('Number of fruits available = ' + str(available))
```

to this line:

```
print('Number of fruits available = {}'.format(len(available)))
```

output:

```
Apple
Item is unavailable
Orange
Item is unavailable
Pear
Item is unavailable
Watermelon
Item is available
The following items are unavailable
['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear']
Number of fruits available = 5
Percentage of fruits available = 62.5
```